# Spring AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor uses only parameter less constructor

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Below is the quote from springs documentation of AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor,

> Only one constructor (at max) of any given bean class may carry this
>   annotation with the 'required' parameter set to true, indicating the
>   constructor to autowire when used as a Spring bean. If multiple
>   non-required constructors carry the annotation, they will be
>   considered as candidates for autowiring. The constructor with the
>   greatest number of dependencies that can be satisfied by matching
>   beans in the Spring container will be chosen. If none of the
>   candidates can be satisfied, then a default constructor (if present)
>   will be used. An annotated constructor does not have to be public.

Since I am new to Spring I just know that when we use `@Autowired` it calls parameterless constructor to inject dependency.

How does this `required` can be used with constructor and what does this quote means?

Answer (score 4):

There are two methods of autowiring things with Spring: field-based and constructor-based. I take it that so far you've only been familiar with autowiring by field. This quote refers to having the `@Autowired` annotation on a constructor instead (or also). This means that Spring will try to autowire constructor parameters. Therefore, you no longer need to have the parameter-less constructor at all.

Constructor-based autowiring is essential if you plan on having your classes immutable, i.e. with fields declares as final which must be autowired.

#### Examples

A simple example can be found [in the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation) (third code sample after the anchor).

A little bit [more complex one](http://geekabyte.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-autowire-bean-with-constructor.html).

[Another one from reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) (second code sample after the anchor).

Comment: Just curious to know how @Autowire can inject dependency by calling parameterized constructor, can you give one example?